# How to return a value from an ajax function containing a each function to the main program?

Tags: jquery, ajax

My `foo()` function returns a `1` value if a person has logged on the selected machine. It returns `0` if the machine is available. I need to use this variable (`log`) in a button click event. However I simply can't figure out how to write a callback in this scenario.

```js
function foo(callback) {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/api/machine/',
    dataType: "JSON",
    data: "data",
    success: function(data) {
      callback(data)

      $.each(data, function(i, data) {
        if (data.machinename == $("#DropDownList2").val()) {
          var log = data.selected;
          alert('Machine status is: ' + log);
        };
      });
    }
  });
}

foo(function(data) {
  alert('Data2 is: ' + data);
});
```

Comment: Put the callback after you set the value of `log`, and use `callback(log)`. The duplicate I linked gives a very good grounding in asynchronous logic, and how callbacks/promises work.

Comment: Well, my dropdownlist selection is not working after moving callback function.